# File upload field doesn't display (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have a django form, but it's not showing the "upload file" field when I render it on my website. What am I doing wrong? Ideally, the form has a question ID associated with it that's submitted automatically (e.g. it doesn't have to be manually put in by the user when uploading the file)

models.py

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    response_file = models.FileField(upload_to='audio_responses')
```

forms.py

```
class PostAudio(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('response_file',)
```

views.py

```
def QuestionRecordSubmitView(request, pk):
    model = Question

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostAudio(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.question_id = pk
            form.save()

            # get survey pk
            question_instance = Question.objects.get(pk=pk)
            survey_pk = question_instance.survey.pk
            return redirect('survey-share',pk=survey_pk)
    else:
        form = PostAudio()
    return render(request, 'survey/question_audio_submit.html')
```

html

```
{% extends "landing/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <h2>New Submission</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Because you did not pass `form` to as `context` dictionary

Answer (score 0):

````
def QuestionRecordSubmitView(request, pk):
    model = Question

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostAudio(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.question_id = pk
            form.save()

            # get survey pk
            question_instance = Question.objects.get(pk=pk)
            survey_pk = question_instance.survey.pk
            return redirect('survey-share',pk=survey_pk)
    else:
        form = PostAudio()
    return render(request, 'survey/question_audio_submit.html', {'form':form})```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.